# Raddoppiamento fonosintattico nel caso della particella "ci"?

Tags: regional, pronunciation

Non capisco se si sia corretto pronunciare "cci sono" o "ci sono" oppure ancora "andiamocci" o "andiamoci" .

So che alcune parole che nello scritto non hanno la doppia la acquisiscono nella pronuncia.

Ora non so se la differenza di pronuncia sia relativa alle varie zone d'Italia.

Tipo al nord si pronuncia "ha detto" così come si legge, mentre a al sud o in Toscana si dovrebbe pronunciare "ha ddetto"

Qual è la verità?

Comment: Facci caso: qui il raddoppiamento c'è. Ma andiamoci piano, non sempre. `;-)`

Comment: Questa domanda (e la successiva risposta di @DaG) mi hanno aperto un mondo: da persona nata e cresciuta a Milano, avrei ascritto qualsiasi raddoppiamento a variazioni dialettali.

Answer (score 4):

Sì, varia abbastanza da una parte d'Italia all'altra. Se vogliamo considerare l'italiano standard, in genere i raddoppiamenti che usano i toscani fanno abbastanza testo, ma non sempre.

In alcuni dizionari viene indicato se una parola o particella dà luogo o no al raddoppiamento fonosintattico, con un segno + o simili. Per esempio, in italiano standard la preposizione “da” provoca il raddoppiamento dopo di sé: “Vengo da Firenze” si pronuncia come se fosse scritto “... daffirenze”. Questo spiega parole come “dabbene”, “davvero” etc. Un dizionario potrebbe indicare questo caso con *da<sup>+</sup>*.

Trovi indicazioni in proposito, per esempio, nel *Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronunzia* ([in rete qui](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/)). Per esempio, la voce relativa a “da” è [qui](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=61519&r=1931).

Per quanto riguarda gli esempi che fai, “[ci](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=70940&r=30987)” non dà luogo di per sé a nessun raddoppiamento (ma la c potrebbe raddoppiarsi a seconda di quello che c'è prima, come in “se ci sei”), mentre “[ha](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=50707&r=11144)” sì, con la parola che segue.

La regola generale (sempre per l'italiano standard) è che si ha il raddoppiamento

> (a) dopo una parola accentata sull’ultima sillaba (ivi inclusi i monosillabi tonici): ad es., andrò [pː]iano, farà [tː]utto, mangerò [tː]utto, va [fː]orte, re [lː]atino, tre [kː]ani;
> (b) dopo una serie di morfemi monosillabici (per es., e, o, ho, è, se) o bisillabici (come, dove, sopra, qualche): ad es., io e [tː]e, ho [fː]ame.

Cito dalla [voce sul raddoppiamento sintattico dell'*Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/raddoppiamento-sintattico_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/), dove ovviamente puoi trovare molti più lumi.

Comment: Quindi "c'era" e "cera" si pronunciano allo stesso modo, cioè con una sola c?

Comment: @Nakamura: Da sole sì; altrimenti dipende da cosa viene prima. Il raddoppiamento fonosintattico, là dove si verifica, è solo tra due parole, cioè per una consonante che si ritrova tra due vocali (come negli esempi che vedi sopra), mai per una consonante da sola all'inizio di una parola. Per esempio, in entrambe, dopo la congiunzione “e” si raddoppierebbe la “c”.

Comment: Ho aggiunto nella risposta che “ci” in effetti potrebbe raddoppiarsi, in funzione di cosa viene prima.

Comment: ("C'era" e "cera" pero' si distinguono per la pronuncia della vocale tonica, rispettivamente /'ɛra/, /'era/.

Comment: Giusto, @AndreaM, il mio “sì” si riferiva specificamente alla domanda di Nakamura, “cioè con una sola c”. Comunque hai fatto bene a sottolinearlo.